# Defining an instance for a composite type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have a type that has a `mappend`-like function but not a real `mappend`, so it is not a `Semigroup`. For instance:

```
data MyType = MyType Int deriving Show

myMerge :: MyType -> MyType -> Maybe MyType
myMerge (MyType x) (MyType y)
  | (x < 0) || (y < 0) = Nothing
  | otherwise          = Just $ MyType $ x + y
```

I always deal with `MyType` when it is wrapped in `Maybe`. I need semantics that would be perfectly represented if I could define a `Semigroup` instance on the "combined" type `Maybe MyType` like this:

```
instance Semigroup (Maybe MyType) where
  (Just x) <> (Just y) = myMerge x y
  Nothing  <> Nothing  = Nothing
  Nothing  <> (Just _) = Nothing
  (Just _) <> Nothing  = Nothing
```

I.e. when both parameters are `Just`'s, I can get either a `Just` or `Nothing`, otherwise I always get `Nothing`. But this is not possible, I get an error:

```
All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
```

How can I represent the semantics that I need?

Comment: Your definition of `myMerge` surely won't compile - the arguments should be `MyType x` and `MyType y`?

Comment: The error should point to some Haskell extensions that should be enabled for the instance to work. Modern Haskell heavily uses many GHC extensions.

Comment: It's unclear what you are actually trying to achieve. Do you just want a type which represents strictly positive integers? The idiomatic way to do this is to define an abstract type with a function `toMyType :: Int -> Maybe MyType` which returns `Nothing` iff the argument is less than 0. Otherwise, I would suggest not trying to fit your type into an interface it doesn't support - it would be idiomatic to define this simply as a free function. (Finally note your `<>` definition is simply `liftA2 myMerge` - it might be easier to just write that inline where needed)

Comment: @user2407038 I don't think this is `liftA2 myMerge`. That would require `myMerge` to have the signature `MyType -> MyType -> MyType`. But `myMerge` can choose to return a Nothing even when given two Justs, which is quite a different kettle of fish.

Comment: @amalloy Indeed, my mistake. It is actually `\x y -> join $ liftA2 myMerge x y` - not quite suitable to inline.

Comment: If you always deal with `MyType` when it is wrapped in `Maybe`, maybe `Maybe` may be better as part of `MyType`?

Comment: @luqui indeed, though in other parts of the code I need it unwrapped. So I would essentially need another type wrapper like amalloy suggest in his answer.

Comment: @RobinZigmond, you are right, corrected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The instance you defined is illegal because it is basically trying to define a different (partial) Semigroup instance for Maybe, but Maybe already has one. Instead, use a newtype wrapper:

```
newtype MaybeMyType = MaybeMyType (Maybe MyType)

instance Semigroup MaybeMyType where
  ...
```

You will have to interact with your type through this MaybeMyType wrapper in the cases where you want to use its Semigroup instance.

Comment: I had a feeling that a type wrapper would do the job, though it looks clunky. But your explanation about me trying to define a second instance for the same type makes sense.

Comment: It's really a simplification: even if Maybe had no Semigroup instance this would be illegal, because you can't define instances for some specializations of a parameterized type but not others. Also I agree with luqui's comment to just include the maybe-ness in your type, if you always work with it that way. Define it as a newtype wrapper over Maybe Int, or make your own equivalent `data` definition.